# DNS server issue in Alpine guest when using qemu-system-aarch64 on Android host

Tags: android, qemu, alpine-linux, udhcpc

When trying to install Alpine via `setup-alpine` on an Android host using qemu-system-aarch64 (for example using Termux), the installation fails when trying to do an initial lookup of Alpine's mirrors:

`wget: bad address 'mirrors.alpinelinux.org'`

At first I suspected the issue to center around the fact that qemu uses the first default DNS server of the host OS (Android in this case), but even adding an explicit DNS server address to the qemu network backend configuration did not solve this:

`-netdev user,id=n0,dns=1.1.1.1 -device virtio-net,netdev=n0`

Neither did adding adding a nameserver manually to `/etc/resolv.conf` after invoking `setup-dns`/ `setup-interfaces` prior to invoking `setup-alpine`. Also adding a `dns-nameserver 1.1.1.1` to the eth0 interface definition as part of the manual network configuration did not solve this issue.

I suspect the RC somewhere to be in between qemu's standard DNS server (10.0.2.3 when using the user networking backend) and Alpine's initial network / DNS configuration when booting from the ´virt´ ISO image.

More than happy to provide additional information as required.

Comment: Your question is off topic. From the dns tag: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Answer (score 0):

The possible work-around that finally allowed me to install the Alpine guest:

1. Boot into the installation ISO using qemu,
2. Create a file `/etc/udhcpc/udhcpc.conf` with the line `RESOLV_CONF="no"` preventing udhcpd (Busybox' DHCP server) from overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`,
3. Create `/etc/resolv.conf` with two (!) nameserver entries (this seems to be important as one nameserver definition does not solve the issue),
4. Conclude the installation via `setup-alpine` as usual.